# Alternatives of using verbs and adjectives in RESTful URL

Tags: rest, api, restful-url

I want to add actions to my REST API that would move 'resources' between different 'stores'.

For instance, suppose my resources are normally accessed by the following URL:

```
/resources
/resources/{resourceId}
```

Now suppose I want to 'deactivate' some resource, i.e. conceptually move it to another sub-folder. The most straightforward way to allow this would be as followed.

1. 'Deactivate' the resource, i.e. cause it to be unavailable under /resources. Conceptually, it 'moves' the object to the '*/resources/deactivated/*' subfolder:

   ```
   POST /resources/{resourceId}/deactivate
   ```

   Or alternatively:

   ```
   POST /resources/deactivated/{resourceId}
   ```
2. Get all the deactivated objects:

   ```
   GET /resources/deactivated
   ```
3. Reverse the 'deactivate' action, i.e. conceptually move the object from the '*/resources/deactivated/*' subfolder back to the main one ('*/resources*').

   Either

   ```
   POST /resources/{resourceId}/reactivate
   ```

   Or

   ```
   POST /resources/deactivated/{resourceId}/restore
   ```

   This API seems rather intuitive for me. But it seems to violate the 'prefer nouns' rules that I have seen in many best practices-articles on REST API: I use verbs and adjectives instead of nouns!

Note that I might have parameters for all the endpoints, e.g. *GET /resources/deactivated?createdBefore=01022017*

**Are there any better alternatives for my REST API? I.e. more RESTful, but not less intuitive ones?**

Good resources that I could find on the topic:

- [Confusion Between Noun vs. Verb in Rest URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121749/confusion-between-noun-vs-verb-in-rest-urls/27122233#27122233)
- GitHub's usage of verbs (POST /gists/:id/star, DELETE /gists/:id/star): https://stackoverflow.com/a/19648997/1847482
- Good point on needing to look for 'another object type': https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022938/1847482

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, remember that **REST** stands for **Re**presentational **S**tate **T**ransfer.

It is all about *resources and their state*. Operations such as *activate*, *deactivate* and *move* are all about replacing the current state of the resource with a new representation and you don't need verbs in the URL to express such operations.

---

For example, to replace a status of a resource, you can send a new representation of the resource in the payload of a `PUT` request:

```
PUT /api/resources/[id]/status HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{ "status" : "active" }
```

It can be understood as *replace the status of the resource identified by `[id]` with the one sent in the request payload*.

---

Then you could have the following to get the resources with a particular status:

```
GET /api/resources?status=active HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Accept: application/json
```

It can be understood as *give me a representation of all resources with the status `active`*.

---

To move a resource to another folder, for example, you could have:

```
PUT /api/resources/[id]/folder HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{ "target" : "draft" }
```

It can be understood as *replace the folder of the resource identified by `[id]` with the one sent in the request payload*.

Comment: I like your answer (voted) as it gives me a better understanding of the REST approach. Yet I don't think simply changing a 'status' attribute would be acceptable in my case, since 'GET /resources' should not return the deactivated ones.

Comment: @Alexander To get all resources you can request `GET /api/resources`. It will return the active and inactive ones. To filter the `resources` collection, you can use a query parameter like `status`. So `GET /api/resources?status=active` would return the active ones, while `GET /api/resources?status=inactive` would return the inactive ones. You could assume default values for your query parameters. If the `status` is ommited, assume that you want only the active ones.

Comment: I disagree. 'GET /resources' should return all the objects, regardless of values of specific attributes, otherwise it is very confusing. But on the other hand, it should not return the 'deactivated' ones, which means it is not simply a regular attribute.

Comment: @Alexander Have a look at the GitHub API to [list issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues): `GET /issues`. The `filter` query parameter can be used to indicates which sorts of issues to return. If no value is provided, the `assigned` value is used as default.

Comment: Thanks Cassio. Well, convinced. They are placing a star on a gist with 'PUT' as well. https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#star-a-gist .

Comment: @cassiomolin - Ironically, given that this question is about avoiding verbs in REST URLs, the GiHub API you referenced actually uses verbs in their URLs in some cases.  See https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#lock-an-issue.  You'll find this in google's BigQuery API's as well https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/, refer to insertAll. The only thing I've found consistent about well known REST APIs is that overall, they're consistently inconsistent.  Sometimes, just making things intuitive is the best approach, even if you're not "pure" by REST standards.

Comment: What would you recommend to use when returning a new instance of a resource? What I mean with new is that I want to have a GET endpoint to call for getting a new instance of some resource with default values set. This new resource is to be displayed in a form and the user will add data to it, and finally a POST will be posted. I cannot come up with a noun for that; only verb (create) or adjective (new).

Answer (score 3):

Is an active resource really that different than a deactivated resource? Consider just having a property that tracks `active`ness. You can always filter them out, such as

```
GET /things?active=true
```

You can alter just that property with a microPUT

```
PUT /things/{id}/active
false
```

If a `thing` and a `deactivated-thing` are conceptually different, it's reasonable to have two separate endpoints. I would move between them using

```
POST `/deactivated-things`
{
    "thing": "/things/12"
}
```

and

```
POST `/things`
{
    "deactivated-thing": "/deactivated-things/12"
}
```

You should try to avoid a path having multiple meanings. For example, don't do this:

```
/resources/{id}
/resources/deactivated/{id}
```

Don't overload the meaning of the path segment after `/resources`.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you never see mentioned with REST:

Don't confuse REST with web app or pretty urls.

eg. when a user logs in to edit their account, you would show

```
www.example.com/home
www.example.com/account
www.example.com/profile
```

and not

```
// www.example.com/users/{id} ...
www.example.com/users/433563444335634443356344
www.example.com/users/433563444335634443356344/edit
```

I think this is where many devs get confused. REST is great for APIs, but in terms of web apps, it should be used as the internal API for form action endpoints or ajax, for example, but not necessarily as the pretty url.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Cassio for emphasizing the 'changing the object state' approach.

My own answer for completeness:

```
PATCH /resources/{resourceId} with body {"active":false}  -- deactivate a resource
PATCH /resources/{resourceId} with body {"active":true}  -- restore a resource
GET    /resources                        -- return all 'normal' resources
GET    /resources?includeInactive=true   -- return all resources including the deactivated ones
GET    /resources/{resourceId}           -- return the resource
```

(The resources retrieved by 'GET' will contain the attribute 'active=true/false').

Seems like a classic case for PATCH: [REST API PATCH or PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24241893/1847482)